# Data not being inserted into Cosmos C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a list of items (32007 of them)

I am adding them in bulk

However, it seems as though some are not being inserted

The even stranger thing is that if I run my process several times from scratch (i.e. recreating my collection), the number items created varies, I have seen 32005, 32003

I have scaled up my collection to have a lot of RUs (Autoscaled) to 25000

I split the data into tranches of 100

My logic is below

```
public async Task<List<Account>> ProcessAccountsAsync(List<Account> accounts)
{
   var cosmosConnection = await ConnectToDatabaseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
   var failedAccounts = new List<Account>();

   var accountsToInsert = new Dictionary<PartitionKey, Stream>(accounts.Count);
   Parallel.ForEach(accounts, (account) =>
   {
       var stream = new MemoryStream();
       var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(account, JsonHelper.DefaultSettings());
       stream.Write(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(json));
       stream.Position = 0;
       accountsToInsert.Add(new PartitionKey(account.Id), stream);
   });

   var tasks = new List<Task>(accounts.Count);
   foreach (var account in accountsToInsert)
   {
       tasks.Add(cosmosConnection.Container.CreateItemStreamAsync(account.Value, account.Key)
            .ContinueWith((Task<ResponseMessage> task) =>
            {
                using (var response = task.Result)
                {
                    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var actualAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault(x => account.Key.ToString().Contains(x.Id));
                        Debug.WriteLine($"Processing Account : {actualAccount?.ArcContactId} Received {response.StatusCode} ({response.ErrorMessage}).");
                        failedAccounts.Add(actualAccount);
                    }
                }
            }));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        return failedAccounts;
    }
```

In my calling logic I retry all accounts that have failed

```
var tidiedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, Formatting.Indented);
accounts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <List<DomainModels.Versions.v2.Account>>(tidiedJson);

var failedAccounts = await cosmosAccountRepository.ProcessAccountsAsync(accounts);

while (failedAccounts.Count > 0)
{
    failedAccounts = await cosmosAccountRepository.ProcessAccountsAsync(failedAccounts);
}
```

I have no idea why accounts are not being inserted and why the behaviour is so random!

I have tried this with a variety of throughput and tranche sizes, no difference

Can anyone see anything obvious?

Failing this, I have the accounts with an ID field, is there a way of finding out which of the accounts are not in the database, without having to go through all 32007 of them one by one, which is obviously not a good plan!

Paul

Comment: `accountsToInsert` is not thread-safe. You can't `Add` to it from multiple threads like that.

Comment: You might consider using a [bulk insert procedure](https://azurecosmosdb.github.io/labs/dotnet/labs/07-transactions-with-continuation.html). I use this and it is lightning fast and will probably save you some RU/s.